# Столкновение 2D фигур друг с другом?

Tags: java

Как можно определить стратегию столкновения фигур друг с другом? Подкиньте какую нить идею, я думал о сравнении координат фигур, на наличие общих точек. Но алгоритм пока не получается придумать, выручайте

Comment: Ну так да, проверка координат. Можно сделать сначала грубую проверку сравнению описывающих прямоугольников) для повышения производительности. А потом искать общие точки. В зависимости от типа фигур нужно по-разному проверять. Искать пересечения попиксельно, конечно, очень неэффективно, но самом худшем случае это так и будет.

Comment: А откуда взялось "попиксельно". Фигура -- это одно, а её отображение в растр -- другое. А так -- искать пересечения границ. (Если пересечений нет, то можно проверить на принадлежность точки меньшей по площади фигуры большей -- меньшая уже внутри)

Answer (score 1):

если это квадраты тогда просто задать чтото типа (суммарная их высота и ширина 10, отсюда и 5)

```
if((x-x1)<5)
{
    if((y-y1)<5)
    {
        ....// действия при столкновении
    }
}
```

если это круги тогда (предположим что сумма радиусов равна 5)

```
x0=x-x1
y0=y-y1
if(Math.sqrt((x0*x0)+(y0*y0))>5)
{
    ...// действия при столкновении
}
```

еще нашел метод который проверяет не содержит ли фигура заданную точку или прямоугольник

```
private Ellipse2D q;

public boolean find(Point2D t)// также может быть Rectangle2D
{
    if(q.contains(t))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Задачка не из тривиальных. Начните с [этого](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection), например. Нужно использовать какие-то алгоритмы из вычислительной геометрии + физика. Возможно, просто стоит взять какой-нибудь физический движок, где эта штука реализована.